# automatically generate invoice number in c# using stored procedure in dapper

Tags: c#, sql-server-2016

I want to generate customize transaction number e.g(INV2019-12-000001) and generate it the next invoice number by saving the data using stored procedure.

Comment: What had you tried so far?

Comment: You can use [Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in the database to create new numbers. Unlike an Identity column, sequences are independent database objects that can be accessed directly. You can reset them once a year or once a month depending on your business logic

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially How to [Ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a sequence object on your database using SQL code similar to:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE Test.CountBy1TestSequence  
    START WITH 1  
    INCREMENT BY 1 ;  
GO
```

This can then be called using SQL with:

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR Test.CountBy1TestSequence;
```

Or called via dapper using:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                String sql = @"SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR Test.CountBy1TestSequence";

                var result = conn.ExecuteScalar<Int>(sql);

                // Do whatever with the result    
            }
```

Using the sequence value you can then pass it to a stored procedure on your database using dapper with similar code to the following:

```
 var p = new DynamicParameters();
 p.Add("@inputInvoiceNumber", $"INV{DateTime.Now.Year}-{DateTime.Now.Month}-{result}, DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input);
 p.Add("@retVal", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.ReturnValue); // If there is any return

 cnn.Execute("spTestProc", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Where `@inputInvoiceNumber` and `@retVal` are parameters in your stored procedure.